# Git push from post-receive

Tags: replication, git

I have two servers, let's call them first and second. First one is where the real development is done, and second one should be the replica. What I would like to do is put "git push" in post-receive, but there is one problem. Post-receive is executed as the user doing git push to first server, so I can't chmod 600 ssh key with no pass. What is the best practice for this? Thanx!

Comment: "Post-receive is executed as the user doing git push to first server" <- why should that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just not give to developers direct SSH to user that running git on 1st server.
Use gitolite to use singe git account on server with key-based authorization without shell access.

Comment: As a bonus, gitolite3 does [mirroring](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/mirroring.html), which is exactly what OP wants to accomplish.